# How to disable keyboard shortcuts on ASUS laptop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, troubleshooting

I just purchased an ASUS N53S laptop and am having problems with the keyboard. Some keys (such as <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, or <kbd>y</kbd>) are bound by default to software shortcuts. For example, <kbd>o</kbd> opens the Power 4 Gear menu, <kbd>y</kbd> opens the help menu etc.

I checked and have **Sticky keys** disabled and the **Windows key** does not seem to be stuck (although when I press the Windows key, it triggers the application Power 4 Gear as well as the control panel). This keyboard problem is driving me nuts. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check Programs and Features list, it may be a Asus program you can remove.

Answer (score 3):

Those types of programs are usually as an application loading during the boot process. I would run HijackThis to see what is loading, particularly in the RUN keys, that is related to ASUS. You may realize which one it is by its name, but if not, Google the names of the ASUS programs to get descriptions. You are bound to hit on it, then check in in HijackThis, and let HJT delete it from the regustry for you.

If you are not sure, post back a screenshot of your HijackThis results, and send me a note @kcotreau.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to make sure you have the latest drivers installed for the system. That doesn't sound like normal behaviour for a new laptop's keyboard, and I would hope that an update to the machines drivers or firmware would make it work more appropriately. Here is a link:
http://www.service.asus.com/
Just go to "download now" and type in your model.

If that doesn't work...maybe the keyboard is not plugged in correctly? But that's a longshot, and may void your warranty if you try to unplug and replug the keyboard cable.
It certainly doesn't hurt to take  user815423426' recommendation either, you can probably just turn off all startup programs that have ASUS in their name or path safely.
I personally would use ccleaner for changing startup items. It doesn't quite show everything that something like Autoruns would show, but it's quick and it's simple.